# Android App using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an Android App using Google Maps

The problem which i am facing right now are :

1. Google Map performance is not good. Are there any techniques to optimize the same?
2. Is there any way to download the Offline maps for the Application, so that user can use the App even if an internet connection is not available?

Please can anyone help me how to resolve this problems?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Android maps do not allow any caching, so you cannot used them offline in your app. You can try OpenStreetMaps, theese allow offline usage.